# How to store snapshot of a spring JPA entity in a new table with new primary key column

Tags: java, jpa

I have couple of entities, Person and PersonSnapshot. PersonSnapshot is same as Person, except for, it has its own primary key.

I would like use Java class hierarchy so that I need not redefine property names, but I am not able to get them to work as the two tables will have different "@Id" properties.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Person")
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
    class Person {
       @Id
       private int id;
       @name
       private String name;
   }
```

I need to store its snapshot as in

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person_Snapshot")
class PersonSnapshot extends Person {
     @Id
     private int snapShotId;
}
```

I don't want to create an abstract MappedSuperClass for common attributes as I will end up with 3 classes. Is there any way achieve the same result with just these two classes ?

Comment: are you aiming to create snapshots for every change of Person?  if so, Hibernate Envers may do the work for you

Comment: I ended up creating 3 classses. At least the code is a bit more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Move everything that is common between the two classes into a superclass and annotate it with `@MappedSuperclass`. For more details see for example this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html